# Metadata info with escape characters when converting into SVG

Tags: svg

I am developing a math animation software that renders LaTeX strings into svg objects using `dvisvgm`. I want the library to be able to identify which svg shapes belong to certain tokens (like "x" or "\sqrt") taking into account that some tokens generate more than one SVG shape. Is there any way to add this info to the generated svg?

Thanks!

Comment: texlive has no software called `dvi2svg` , do you mean `dvisvgm` ?

Comment: Yes, I mean dvisvgm, sorry for the confussion!

Comment: you can edit the question

Comment: Done, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with most DVI drivers, you can insert information using `\special`, the `dvisvgm` manual details the possibilities.

Here I use `dvisvgm:raw` which inserts raw svg fragments into the generated SVG.

These fragments are merged into the result SVG with little checking so it is very easy to corrupt the output, but with care you can do things. Possibly safest is to insert SVG (XML) comments but they are harder to extract information from. Here I wrap things in `<g class="...">...</g>` where `<g>` is the svg scope group which is more or less safe in most places, and use css classes (here undefinied) to annotate terms of the expression.

so

```
\documentclass{article}
\protected\def\m#1#2{%
\special{dvisvgm:raw <g class="#1">}%
#2%
\special{dvisvgm:raw </g>}%
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\[
\m{lhs}{\m{sqrt}{\sqrt{\m{power}3^2+\m{power}{4^2}}}}
=
\m{rhs}{5}
\]
\end{document}
```

Produces an SVG that displays as:

[image]

But has an internal structure showing powers and square roots etc:

[image]

The image generated actually had the top rule of the `\sqrt` I just clipped it by mistake, the left hand `√` is missing for unrelated reasons, using an up to date texlive 2023 I get

[image]

from

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
Sqrt?
\[
\sqrt{3^2+4^2}
\]
\end{document}
```

which looks like a bug somewhere.

Comment: oh I lost the sqrt sign,  let me check.....

Comment: Thank you very much! With this idea I can preprocess the LaTeX string for each command/token and add the appropriate markers. Thanks again!